# Call a MVC action method from Winform application with post data and open the response in an external browser

Tags: c#, winforms, winforms-to-web

I need to open an url in an external browser from my Winforms application by calling a MVC action method and post data of type json.

I could do it using the `WebBrowser` component but my requirement is to open it in a browser.